# Custom `filter` function using guards

Tags: erlang

I was trying to write my own `filter` function and ran into an error. The code:

```
filter_acc(_, [], Result) -> Result;
filter_acc(F, [H|T], Result) when F(H) =:= true -> filter_acc(F, T, [H | Result]).
filter(F, L) -> filter_acc(F, L, []).
```

The error:

```
my_functions.erl:11: illegal guard expression
error
```

Can functions not be evaluated as part of guard expressions? If not, how is this to be done?

Comment: in order to guarantee the performances only a few set of short BIF and comparisons are allowed in guard (with an exception: length that may be very long if the list is huge).

Comment: @Pascal it's not just performance. Guards and conditional statements in 'if' blocks cannot run code that has side-effects, so they limit it functions known to be side-effect free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it like this (only with function clause, no need of guards) but I am afraid it has few interest.

```
1> FA = fun FA(_,[H],true,R) -> [H|R];
1> FA(_,[_],_,R) -> R;
1> FA(F,[H1,H2|T],true,R) -> FA(F,[H2|T],F(H2),[H1|R]);
1> FA(F,[_,H2|T],_,R) -> FA(F,[H2|T],F(H2),R) end.  
#Fun<erl_eval.28.50752066>
2> Filter = fun(_,[]) -> []; (F,L= [H|_]) -> FA(F,L,F(H),[]) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.50752066>
3> Filter(fun(X) -> X > 4 end,[1,2,5,hello,"Joe"]).
["Joe",hello,5]
4>
```

Comment: More than interest, I fund this intimidating! :D Thanks for the the effort, though. I will study it someday soon. :-)